# Representation of dense Subset

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, representation-theory, c-star-algebras

let $\mathcal B \subset \mathcal A$ a dense subset of a C*-algebra $\mathcal A$.

I have a representation for $\mathcal B$. Can I then conclude that this is somehow also a representation for $\mathcal A$?

By a representation for $\mathcal B$, I mean that I have a Hilbertspace $H$ and a *-homomorphism $\pi: \mathcal B \rightarrow \mathcal L (H)$. With $\mathcal{L}(H)$ I mean the bounded operators on $H$.

Cheers
Peter

Comment: What do you mean under "representation of a subset"?

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: I think I know what you mean ($a,b,ab\in \mathcal B$ implies $\pi(ab)=\pi(a)\pi(b)$ etc.). However homomorphisms are defined only for algebraic structures (groups, rings etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your representation is a bounded linear map, it extends to $\mathcal A$. Then, using the density, you prove that it is also a $*$-homomorphism. Of course, as Yurii mentioned, this works if $\mathcal B$ is a subalgebra; if it is not, it is not really clear what "representation" would be.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, the answer is no. Let $\mathcal A=\mathbb C,\mathcal B=\mathbb Q[\pi]+i\mathbb Q[\pi]\simeq(\mathbb Q+i\mathbb Q)[x].$ Define $\varphi:\mathcal B\to \mathbb C,\ \varphi(p(\pi))=p(0),$ where $p\in(\mathbb Q+i\mathbb Q)[x].$ Then $\pi$ is a non-zero homomorphism. It cannot be extended to the identity mapping $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C.$

Comment: Okay, given the C*-algebra $\mathcal A =\mathbb C$. Now you take the subspace $\mathcal B = \mathbb Q + i \mathbb Q$ which is obviously dense. Now I assume, that I have a representation on $\mathcal B$, i.e. a *-homomorphism $\pi: \mathcal B \to \mathcal L(H)$, where H is a suitable Hilbertspace. The question is now whether this $\pi$ can be extended on the whole algebra. I just see that this might work with the bounded linear extension theorem.

Comment: If you add boundedness and linearity of $\mathcal B$ then it should work.